# Mapping Home folders using Powershell sets it in AD but does nothing else

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want my Active Directory users to have their own Home folder to store their files and I want to set this for each user account via PowerShell. I've tried several things but all it does is change the setting under "*profile*" in AD to the homefolder location, and this does not seem to show up for the users when they log in.

Some of the code i've tried:

```
    SET-ADUSER inggul –HomeDrive ‘P:’ –HomeDirectory ‘\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\$Inggul’

    $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=sAdminOU,dc=kossi,dc=local" -Filter * -Properties Department
    foreach ($user in $users)
    {
    Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory "\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\($_.SamAccountName)"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your PowerShell, the first command looks like it should work to me. Your `ForEach` loop has an issue though, it's referencing `$_` instead of `$user`. It should be:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Set-ADUser $user.SamAccountName -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory "\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\$($user.SamAccountName)"
}
```

`$_` is used to represent the current item in the pipeline within a `ForEach-Object` loop (or within other constructs that are handling input from the pipeline such as `Where-Object` for example). You are also missing a `$` in front of `($user.SamAccountName)`. It needs to be `$($user.SamAccountName)`, the `$() part is the subexpression operator that ensures that the`SamAccountName`property of`$user` is correctly accessed before being converted to a string within the double quoted string.

Per the other answer, if the home directory still isn't being mapped on logon then you may also need to ensure that each user has share and NTFS permissions to their directory.

Comment: @Martin: yup .Change it and try once . even you can use [THIS SCRIPT](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-create-home-folder-d968f1d4)

Comment: "The first command looks like it should work to me." It doesn't... Thats why im asking.. It gives the proper information to AD, but it seems as if AD doesn't care about what the home folder location is.. It just overlooks it when the users are logging in..

Comment: Sorry, just realised that was the nature of your question. I've edited my answer, basically you need to do a second step which is set up a GPO to map the users profile path in AD to the my documents folder. Just setting the profile in AD doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: Martin isn't using Folder Redirection, he's using a Home Drive. They are different approaches to centralising user data.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. Are they mapped automatically then, or do you still need to switch it on via GPO?

Comment: Well i have a gpo that sets a home folder individually for every person, but i want to know how to do it With PowerShell, and if possible; With PowerShell only.

Comment: Yeah from a quick Google it looks like home directories are just auto mapped once set in AD, unless your org has that explicitly disabled maybe. My guess is that (per James' answer) you need to make sure the directory exists and the user has both share and NTFS permissions to it.

Comment: As an aside, this question might do better on ServerFault.

Comment: I dont think that is the issue. I have ~6 People besides me With the same issue, we are all on different servers, and all we have done is install AD, DHCP and so on. I might try posting it on ServerFault too..

Answer (score 1):

When you setup a Home Folder using the AD Console it also creates the users folder in the location specified (`\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome`) and assigns the required permissions for the user to access the folder.

Using the PowerShell command does not create the folder or assign any permissions, it only updates the attributes in the users account.

You need to update your script to create the folder and set the permissions:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
$username = $user.SamAccountName
Set-ADUser $username -HomeDrive "Z:" -HomeDirectory "\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\$username"
New-Item -Path "\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\$username" -ItemType Directory
#Set appropriate ntfs permissions here
}
```

Comment: New-Item : \\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\inggul
At line:4 char:1
+ New-Item -Path "\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\$username" -ItemType Directory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\WIN-L372AGVF8AI\NewHome\inggul:String) [New-Item], Argume 
   ntException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: I got that error twice. All i changed is "$_.samaccountname" to "inggul" (a user)..